# Groovy calling smbclient process is not working from Jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am trying to execute `smbclient` command from `jmeter` using `groovy` using below script

```
String command = 'smbclient -U user%pass //100.97.59.95/Shares -c "scopy  download\\\\temp.zip test.zip"'

    OUT.println('Command to run: '+command)
    def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
    def proc_update = command.execute()
    proc_update.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
    proc_update.waitFor()
    println("command ouput :")
    println "out> $sout err> $serr"
```

And below are the tracebacks

```
File to copy: temp.zip
Command to run: smbclient -U user%pass//100.97.59.95/Shares -c "scopy  download\temp.zip test.zip"
command ouput :
out> scopy <src> <dest>
 err> WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Domain=[WIN-VLTIKCNNV6P] OS=[Windows Server 2012 Datacenter 9200] Server=[Windows Server 2012 Datacenter 6.2]
```

The command is working fine from my terminal, not from Groovy. What can be the reason?

Comment: https://ixnfo.com/en/solution-warning-the-syslog-option-is-deprecated.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to use JMeter built-in test elements where possible as [none of available scripting engines provides the same performance as Java code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) so I would suggest going for the [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) instead. The relevant configuration would be something like:

- Command: `/bin/bash`
- Parameter 1: `-c`
- Parameter 2: `smbclient '//100.97.59.95/Shares' -c 'lcd /tmp; cd download; get temp.zip' -U user%pass`

[image]

You will be able to see/get STDOUT/ERR output as for any other sampler, i.e. you can visualize it using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri that's really helpful